# Modify restangular service path

Tags: angularjs, restangular

Now i am creating one service like that :

```
angular.module('test')
.factory('AccountResource', function Account(Restangular) {
    return Restangular.service('accounts');
});
```

and now the path is /accounts so i just inject that service into one of my controller

```
.controller('ProfileChangePasswordFormController', function ($scope, AccountResource) {
$scope.changePassword = function(){

        console.log("change passord send request " );
        console.log($scope.password);

        AccountResource.post("chage_password",$scope.password).then(function() {
            console.log("Object saved OK");
        }, function() {
            console.log("There was an error saving");
        });
    };
```

}

As you can see my rest resource that change password is under /accounts/change_password . But i not to know how add /change_password into existed restangular service ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify your factory to something like below

```
angular.module('test')
 .factory('AccountResource', function Account(Restangular) {
      function accounts(){
        return Restangular.service('accounts');
       }
      function changePassword(){
        return Restangular.service('change_password');
       }
 return {
     accounts:accounts,
     changePassword:changePassword
     }
});
```

and in your controller you can use it

```
AccountResource.changePassword.post("chage_password",$scope.password).then(function()      {
        console.log("Object saved OK");
    }, function() {
        console.log("There was an error saving");
    });
```